# Jquery For Loop ends code

Tags: jquery, api, loops, for-loop, ujs

I have 2 for loops running one behind the other. Both loops pretty much do the same thing with different information but the problem is which ever loop I put first runs, and everything after that loop no matter what code will not run. Both loops work perfectly but all depending on which one is earlier in the lines of code, it will also not execute anything after that first loop. Can anyone tell me why? here is my code

```
for (i = 0; purplerescount.length; i++) {
    if (pbigone[i].length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" + purplerescount[i],
          method: "GET",
          data:{
          api_key: "60304d9a-bf05-49ce-bd2a-30e6cc3f3863"
          },
          success: function(response) {
            var results = response.key
            var square = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.12.1/img/champion/" + results + ".png"
            $('#purpleresults').append("<img id='counterpics' src=" + square + ">")
          }
        });
        pbigone[i].forEach(function(entry){
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" + entry,
              method: "GET",
              data:{
              api_key: "60304d9a-bf05-49ce-bd2a-30e6cc3f3863"
              },
              success: function(response) {
                var results = response.key
                var square = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.12.1/img/champion/" + results + ".png"
                $('#purpleresults').append("<img id='counterpics' src=" + square + ">")
              }
            });
        });
    }
}

for (x = 0; bluerescount.length; x++) {
    if (bbigone[x].length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" + bluerescount[x],
          method: "GET",
          data:{
          api_key: "5a3cb583-47f0-4344-89ab-6c52b15f4082"
          },
          success: function(response) {
            var results = response.key
            var square = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.12.1/img/champion/" + results + ".png"
            $('#blueresults').append("<img id='counterpics' src=" + square + ">")
          }
        });
        bbigone[x].forEach(function(entry){
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" + entry,
              method: "GET",
              data:{
              api_key: "5a3cb583-47f0-4344-89ab-6c52b15f4082"
              },
              success: function(response) {
                var results = response.key
                var square = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.12.1/img/champion/" + results + ".png"
                $('#blueresults').append("<img id='counterpics' src=" + square + ">")
              }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a condition for when the loops are considered finished.

```
for (i = 0; purplerescount.length < i; i++) { ... }
```

and

```
for (x = 0; bluerescount.length < x; x++) { ... }
```

else they'll run forever (try using console.log("test") inside first loop and you'll see it prints infinitely).

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) for further info.

Comment: conditions are backwards